# Navigating to cart screen with stack navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having a stack navigator that consists of 7 different screens and a cart icon is placed on the every screen header. I want to navigate by pressing that cart icon to the cart screen/page. I tried to put onPress function on the icon and in the header option also but all in vain.
Also, I want to know how the cart system will work.
Below is my single stack navigator screen

```
<HomeStack.Screen name="EARRINGS" component={Earring}
options={{headerRight:() => <ShoppingCartIcon /> }}         
 />
```

Below is my ShoppingCartIcon code:

```
const ShoppingCartIcon = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
       
            <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: -20,  right: 0, width: 70, height: 70, alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center", zIndex:2000 }}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20,fontWeight:"bold"}}>0</Text>
            </View>
            <AntDesign name="shoppingcart" color="black" size={24} style={{marginRight:10}} />
    </View>
    )
  }


export default (ShoppingCartIcon)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the navigation prop like below

```
<HomeStack.Screen
    name="EARRINGS"
    component={Earring}
    options={({ navigation }) => ({
      headerRight: () => (<ShoppingCartIcon navigation={navigation}/> )
    })}
  />
```

And you can use the navigation prop to navigate to any screen you need

```
const ShoppingCartIcon = ({navigation}) => {
  //other code
  navigation.navigate('Cartscreen')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I passed the navigation prop in stack navigator and in cartIcon page ```<AntDesign name="shoppingcart" color="black" size={24} style={{marginRight:10}} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("CART")}   />``` did this. But still this  is not working. Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: you get the navigation prop right ? and "cart" is a valid screen right ?

Comment: Yup, I passed props ```const ShoppingCartIcon = ({navigation}) => {``` and CART is the valid screen.

Comment: Ok the issue is with the wrapper view of the text which has the absolute position, the onpress is not working when the absolute position is used, can you remove that and try ?

Comment: you can check the snack here https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/fascinated-turkish-delight

Comment: I checked the expo snack and it is working fine. I will edit my code later as i m travelling now. But then how to fix that number in the cart as without absolute position it wouldn't look nice. Moreover could you please guide me on how the cart system will work.

Comment: If you could tell me style you need i can help you with that, for cart you will have to maintain it in a context or redux state if you are using redux

Comment: It could be any style, My requirement is just a cart icon with a number on it. Not familiar with redux, I have to study it and then might be I Can apply

Comment: Ok wrapped the content with a touchableopacity you can check the snack and it uses your style :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218096/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-lovepreet-singh).